# Celery revoke old task if new one is created with same arguments

Tags: django, celery, scheduled-tasks, django-celery, celery-task

I'm having trouble understanding the Celery queue and revokes. My main question is how to revoke (stop from executing) tasks that are already in the queue if a new task with the same name and arguments is created. so in pseudo-code

```
new_task_to_be_added = some_task(1,2)
if exists some_task in queue where some_task.args = (1,2):
    remove such task from queue
new_task_to_be_added.add_to_queue()
```

this is connected to password reset mechanism - User clicks 'create temporary password' and has 5 minutes to use this password to create a new - permanent - password. If the new password is not set in this time the account should be locked. But if after lets say 4 minutes user creates a new temporary password he should again have 5 minutes to change it but the "lock account" task will trigger in 1 minute - I want to stop that and always only use the newest task (with the same parameters)

this is not a copy of:
[Revoke celery tasks with same args/kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830821/revoke-celery-tasks-with-same-args-kwargs)
this is actually reversed problem